# What is the name of the color used by the SBB (Swiss Federal Railway) in the 1920s to paint their locomotive?

Tags: 1920s, switzerland, railroads

I am trying to find the name of the **green** color that the wonderful [Ce 6/8 II "Crocodile" locomotives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_(locomotive)) wore while driving across the alps during the 1920s and after. This green is very typical of the SBB at this time with other rolling material wearing it too (Ae 6/6, Ae 4/7, ...).

I tried to go through the SLM archives that can be found on the SBB website : https://www.sbbarchiv.ch/archivplansuche.aspx. I also tried to search information related to the Maerklin model : https://www.maerklin.de/en/products/details/article/55681. All this with not much success unfortunately :/
I am pretty sure this color has a name and a color code as it was widely used back then.

I thank you very much for your response and hope this question fits in this StackExchange.

Comment: I would recommend trying to have a look at railway modelling sources, though I am afraid I have no idea where to start: they are often quite scrupulous about such things and it is a good chance that someone somewhere has tracked down the original sources.

Answer (score 16):

[@Siloch@rmweb.co.uk](https://www.rmweb.co.uk/topic/33463-questions-of-swiss-colour-and-french-numbers/?do=findComment&comment=355280) says [NCS* 8010-B90G](https://ncscolour.com/product/s-8010-b90g/), which is closest (but not exact) to [RAL 6009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAL_colours#RAL_6009). The German wikipedia page for the Ae 6/6 calls the color "tannengrün", which is the name of RAL 6009. The source seems to be official documents hosted on the SwissRailModeling Yahoo group, which as far as I know is lost to time.

The image you linked is quite weathered, [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Re_4-4_I_10044_bei_Otelfingen.jpg) shows newer paint.

Comment: A not-always appreciated problem which faces modellers of my favourite rail livery, British Railways Southern Region electric multiple-unit green (1948 to 1966 approx) is that batches of paint differed slightly; the shade when newly painted was not the same as after a year or two of exposure to sunlight, and BR (S) used to repaint and varnish every 10 years and re-varnish at the 5 year point between. All these things made the actual shade at any one point a variable one.

Comment: Not sure where you got "the source seems to be" from, but are you perhaps referring to [this](https://swissrail.groups.io/g/modelling/message/218) or [that](https://swissrail.groups.io/g/modelling/message/220) message? The thread appears to be about [BT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodensee%E2%80%93Toggenburg_railway) not SBB though

Comment: The biggest _advantage_ is that the model _doesn't_ have to be painted a precise color. Something close 100% works because it's "the original color, but it's faded & weathered a bit over time. TBH, it's about ready to go to the paint shop again for a refresh". :)

Comment: @FreeMan - I know purists who 'weather' their rolling stock, some even add tags from imaginary graffiti artists, and I know of one guy who reproduces the effects on blue British Rail 70s-era multiple units caused by chemicals in the wash fluid used in the carriage washer plant, streaks, faded patches, etc.

Answer (score 15):

> … the green color that the wonderful Ce 6/8 II "Crocodile" locomotives wore while driving across the alps during the 1920s …

Well since you specifically ask about the 1920s, it appears that the answer is "none". According to all sources I could find, specifically https://www.stummiforum.de/t19973f20-SBB-Krokodil-Braun-oder-gr-n.html or https://lokifahrer.ch/Lokomotiven/Loks-SBB/Ce_6-8-II/SBB-Ce_6-8-II.htm, the crocodiles wore brown at that time. The green livery didn't come until the 1930s and even then it took a long time to convert the whole fleet.

If you're really curious and need a definitive answer, I suppose you'll find it in the [dossier KDII_DIV_SBB66_0133 "*Anstrich der elektrischen Lokomotiven*" ("coating of the electric locomotives")](https://www.sbbarchiv.ch/detail.aspx?ID=502555) which is available to order from the SBB archive.

Answer (score 10):

Looking up colour standards, it seems plausible that this green was defined in the [RAL classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAL_colour_standard#RAL_Classic) colour system, which is widely used in Europe and was created in the 1920s. My colour vision is not very good, but it looks to me like a slightly faded version of [RAL 6000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAL_colours#RAL_6000), "Patina Green".